# Queue photo uploads to Flickr

Tags: flickr

I would like to do a 365 project on Flickr, but don't really want to upload my pictures one/day, but rather do a series of uploads in a queue, or at least with programmable publications dates, so that I can do my, say next ten days, in one go – and each day one picture gets uploaded/activated at Flickr.

Is there a way to schedule uploads to Flickr?

Comment: Made question to be about the problem to be solved, rather than asking for recommendations for an app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a web app for that purpose: [FlickrQ](http://flickrq.com/)

Comment: Now, if there would be a Lightroom Plugin that could support FlichrQ :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an app that purports to do just that: Flickr Schedulr

http://schedulr.codeplex.com/